# JQuery Datepicker in Grails, controller receiving null

Tags: grails, datepicker

So, I installed http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui, to use the JQuery Datepicker instead of the default Grails datepicker.

The problem is, when the controller receives the value, It gives null, I dont know how to get the value.

Case 1. What I have in my gsp:

```
<input type="text" id="fechaEstimadaInicio" name="fechaInicio" value="${pasantiaCortaInstance?.fechaInicio}">
```

the "fechaEstimadaInicio" is my JQuery Datepicker.

Case 2. Before the JQuery Datepicker, I had this:

```
    <g:datePicker relativeYears="[-7..7]" id="fechaEstimadaInicio" name="fechaInicio" precision="day"  value="${pasantiaCortaInstance?.fechaInicio}"  />
```

And in my controller I tried this:

```
 @Transactional
    def save(PasantiaCorta pasantiaCortaInstance) {
        println pasantiaCortaInstance.fechaInicio
}
```

In Case 1 it gives:
Fri Mar 28 00:00:00 VET 2014

In case 2: null

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT:**

Adavis do you mean something like this?

Before the taglib experiment my JQuery Datepicker looked like this:

```
<g:field type="text" id="fechaDeAprobada" name="fechaDeAprobada" value="${pasantiaCortaInstance?.fechaAprobada}"></g:field>
```

And in a JSScript:

```
...
        $("#fechaDeAprobada").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd'

        });
...
```

I created the TagLib, and now instead of the g:field I have

```
<g:jqDatePicker id="fechaDeAprobada" name="fechaDeAprobada" />
```

But it still prints the taglib like text
I didn't change anything in the head

EDIT2:

Yes it is working with a new example.gsp; but if I try to use it in the static scaffold, the _form.gsp and the create.gsp it doesn't work.

This is the form in the create.gsp

```
<g:form url="[resource:pasantiaCortaInstance, action:'save']" >
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <g:render template="form"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            <g:jqDatePicker id="fechaEstimadaInicio" name="fechaInicio" class="datepicker" value="" /> 
            </g:form>
```

And in the _form.gsp:

```
<div
    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: pasantiaCortaInstance, field: 'fechaInicio', 'error')} required">
    <label for="fechaInicio"> <g:message
            code="pasantiaCorta.fechaInicio.label" default="Fecha Inicio" /> <span
        class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label> 
<g:jqDatePicker id="fechaEstimadaInicio" name="fechaInicio" class="datepicker" value="" /> 
</div>
```

Done, the last problem was the "required"

Comment: I'd look at the `params` object in your controller I believe it's splitting the date into individual values like day month year.  So in your controller you'd probably see params.day, params.month, etc. having values.  I'm not sure how you tell it to make 1 date value for the `fechaInicio` value though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a **custom taglib** in my project, this was modified from another version online but it supports date names that include *"dots"*, like *"myClass.fieldName"*.  The other version didn't.

```
<g:jqDatePicker name="fechaInicio" class="datepicker" value="" />


class jqueryDatePickerTagLib {

    def jqDatePicker = {attrs, body ->
        def out = out
        def name = attrs.name    //The name attribute is required for the tag to work seamlessly with grails
        def id = attrs.id ?: name
        def minDate = attrs.minDate
        def showDay = attrs.showDay
        def val = attrs.value ?: ''

        //Create date text field and supporting hidden text fields need by grails
        out.println "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${name}\" id=\"${id}\" value=\"${val}\" class=\"datepicker input-small\"/>"
        out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_day\" id=\"${id}_day\" />"
        out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_month\" id=\"${id}_month\" />"
        out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_year\" id=\"${id}_year\" />"

        //Code to parse selected date into hidden fields required by grails
        out.println "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \$(document).ready(function(){"
        out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}']\").datepicker({"
        out.println "onClose: function(dateText, inst) {"
        out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}']\").attr(\"value\",dateText);"
        out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_month']\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getMonth() +1);"
        out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_day']\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getDate());"
        out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_year']\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getFullYear());"
        out.println "}"

        //If you want to customize using the jQuery UI events add an if block an attribute as follows
        if(minDate != null){
            out.println ","
            out.println "minDate: ${minDate}"
        }

        if(showDay != null){
            out.println ","
            out.println "beforeShowDay: function(date){"
            out.println "var day = date.getDay();"
            out.println "return [day == ${showDay},\"\"];"
            out.println "}"
        }

        out.println "});"

        if (val != '') {
            out.println("\n")
            out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_month']\").attr(\"value\",new Date('${val}').getMonth() +1);"
            out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_day']\").attr(\"value\",new Date('${val}').getDate());"
            out.println "\$(\"input[name='${name}_year']\").attr(\"value\",new Date('${val}').getFullYear());"
        }

        out.println "})</script>"

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think I am doing something wrong; created a new taglib (New->Taglib) with that code,then added the line of code to the gsp; the gsp is showing the outputs like labels:

<input type="text" name="fechaEstimadaInicio" id="fechaEstimadaInicio" value="" /> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#fechaEstimadaInicio").datepicker({ onClose: function(dateText, inst) { if(dateText){ var selDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateText); } } }); })</script>

Comment: You still need to include the datepicker Javascript file in your gsp. Are you doing that?

Comment: This should be in your head tag: `<g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <jqui:resources />`, unless you are using the resources plugin.  Then it should be `<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>`

Comment: I didn't change anything in my head tag. A g:field works, displays the JQuery Datepicker without problem; when I declare the g:jqDatePicker it only shows text without a field.I updated the question

Comment: if you want to work with dd/mm/yyyy format; what changes do you need to apply in the taglib?
(If you can you can answer in my new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525927/jquery-datepicker-grails-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 3):

A custom TagLib I found to be the best solution. I found this one online and it works like a dream. I made some slight changes because it was returning a lot of unnecessary data for my uses. This will literally just return the date as mm/dd/yy to your controller.

```
class JQDatepickerTagLib {

def jqDatePicker = { attrs, body ->
    def out = out
    def name = attrs.name //The name attribute is required for the tag to work seamlessly with grails
    def id = attrs.id ?: name
    def value = attrs.value
    def displayFormat = attrs.displayFormat
    def datepickerFormat = attrs.datepickerFormat

    def displayFormatString = displayFormat ? displayFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy"
    def datepickerFormatString = datepickerFormat ? datepickerFormat : "mm/dd/yy"
    def dateString = value ? value.format(displayFormatString) : ""

    //Create date text field and supporting hidden text fields need by grails
    out.println "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${name}\" id=\"${id}\" value=\"${dateString}\" />"

    //Code to parse selected date into hidden fields required by grails
    out.println "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \$(document).ready(function(){"
    out.println "\$(\"#${name}\").datepicker({"
    out.println "onClose: function(dateText, inst) {"
    out.println "if(dateText){"
    out.println "var selDate = \$.datepicker.parseDate('${datepickerFormatString}', dateText);"
    out.println "}"
    out.println "}"
    out.println "});"
    out.println "})</script>"
}

}
```

And then simply in your GSP add this :

```
<g:jqDatePicker name="date"></g:jqDatePicker>
```

and BOOM!! you got a fancy date picker that will be sent back to your controller with any actionSubmit. Change the format of the date in the tag lib. Happy coding :)

Comment: Hmmm, I think I am doing something wrong; created a new taglib (New->Taglib) with that code,then added the line of code to the gsp; the gsp is showing the outputs like labels: <input type="text" name="fechaEstimadaInicio" id="fechaEstimadaInicio" value="" /> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#fechaEstimadaInicio").datepicker({ onClose: function(dateText, inst) { if(dateText){ var selDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateText); } } }); })</script>

Comment: Thats correct. And if you wrap all that in a g:formRemote or a g:form, the date will get sent back to the controller as 'mm/dd/yy'

Comment: For example if I create a new gsp, it works; but if I am using grails scaffold with the _form.gsp and the "create.gsp" it doesn't:

<g:form url="[resource:pasantiaCortaInstance, action:'save']" >
    <fieldset class="form">
     <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the first results to be returned for "grails datepicker". I tried following some of the suggestions here and had trouble getting them to work. After quite a bit more searching I found that it was relatively easy to get Date objects working. This assumes the jquery and jquery-ui plugins are installed correctly. I had trouble with these too and finally resorted to the following steps to get jquery-ui installed (there are probably more elegant ways).

- install the '[resources](http://grails.org/plugin/resources)' plugin,
- download jquery and jquery-ui
- copy *.js files into web-app/js
- copy *.css and image directories/files into web-app/css
- [Update the view/layouts/main.gsp](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/1.%20Overview.html#1.1.1%20Make%20sure%20jQuery%20plugin%20is%20installed)

### Example Class

```
public DomainObjectWithDate {
   Date currentDateTime = new Date()
   Date currentDate = new Date()
}
```

### Adding JQuery-ui datepicker to the Grails scaffold templates

Edit the /src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template file (assuming your are using the scaffold templates) and replace the renderDateEditor with a simple input field with the jquery-ui datepicker function attached to it.

NOTES:

1. **Domain Object Date to Field string**: The g:formatDate element converts the Domain Objects Date field into a format that can be read by both the datepicker and the "grails.databinding.dateFormats" data binding definitions. It references the property 'datetime.date.format', defined in a messages.properties file in SimpleDateFormatter syntax
2. **datepicker to Field string**: The dateFormat property tells the datepicker to write the date in a format that the Data Binding configuration, can parse. The syntax seems peculiar to the datepicker.
3. **timepicker**: Time can also be easily added using [other jquery add ons](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). You must ensure that the time format also matches the Data Binding configuration

Example Code:

```
private renderDateEditor(domainClass, property) {
    def precision = (property.type == Date || property.type == java.sql.Date ||    property.type == Calendar) ? "day" : "minute";
    if (!cp) {
        return "<g:datePicker name=\"${property.name}\" precision=\"${precision}\" value=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" />"
    } else {
        if (!cp.editable) {
            return "\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}?.toString()}"
        } else {
            def out = new StringBuffer("")

            out << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${property.name}\" id=\"${property.name}\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" formatName=\"datetime.date.format\" />\"/>"
            out << """<g:javascript>
                          \$(function() {
                              \$( "#${property.name}" ).datepicker(
                              {
                                   dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd',
                              });
                          })
                      </g:javascript>"""
            return out.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

### Data Binding Date string from Form Field

To read the a date string from a form field, you need to do one or more of the following:

1. **GLOBAL**:Add this property to the grails-app/conf/Config.properties. Change it to use your own [date formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as required. Read more about it under [Date Formats For Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding).

   grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
       'yyyy/MM/dd', 
       'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'
   ]
2. **LOCAL**: Add a @BindingFormat('yyyy/MM/dd') to the Date property in the Class definition